# How to draw Euler diagram with highcharts library?

Tags: charts, highcharts, venn-diagram

I want to draw a chart like the following image. How can I do that using Highcharts library?[image: euler-diagram-example]

I am able to get concentric circle in highcharts but not like this. Please help.

Or suggest me a library if the job can be done with that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `venn` series type and manually position circle elements in the load event, for example:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var points = this.series[0].points,
                    point1R = points[0].shapeArgs.r;

                points[1].graphic.attr({
                    x: points[1].graphic.getBBox().x - (point1R - points[1].shapeArgs.r)
                });

                points[2].graphic.attr({
                    x: points[2].graphic.getBBox().x - (point1R - points[2].shapeArgs.r)
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/padhgfe9/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.venn